# Upload files from Unix to Sharepoint directory

Tags: sharepoint-server, file-upload, linux

I need to upload files from Unix directory into SharePoint 2010. This has turned out to be a mountain that I am having significant difficulty climbing, please assist, sample codes will be appreciated. My options are to use either a bash script, java or python code to get this working. A bonus would be also copy files from SharePoint back to Unix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it myself yet, but this seems to be promising for python: [sharepy](https://github.com/JonathanHolvey/sharepy)

There is an example about how to download a file.

If server-side javascript is an option, I would recommend request-sp. I make most calls with it and authentication is supplied by username:password.

Most file operations can be done with the REST interface of SharePoint. As you said, authentication can be a bit tricky.

You can upload a file by POST-ing to this url

example.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle("LIST_NAME")/rootfolder/files/add

You have to add your file to the buffer of the POST-request.

Additional properties could be set with a merge request, but I have never done that so I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint provides web services. Your case you can use Copy service end point.

Here is an example of how to do this in Java http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078906/enterprise-java/java-tip-consuming-sharepoint-web-services-with-a-java-client.html

```
protected  void uploadDocument(CopySoap port, String sourceUrl)   throws Exception {

    File f = new File(sourceUrl);
    logger.debug("Uploading: " + f.getName());

    String url = getProperties().getProperty("copy.location") + f.getName();
    DestinationUrlCollection destinationUrlCollection = new DestinationUrlCollection();
    destinationUrlCollection.getString().add(url);
    if(getProperties().getProperty("copy.location2") != null){
         url = getProperties().getProperty("copy.location2") + f.getName();
         destinationUrlCollection.getString().add(url);
    }


    FieldInformation titleFieldInformation = new FieldInformation();
    titleFieldInformation.setDisplayName("Title");
    titleFieldInformation.setType(FieldType.TEXT);
    titleFieldInformation.setValue(f.getName());

    FieldInformationCollection fields = new FieldInformationCollection();
    fields.getFieldInformation().add(titleFieldInformation);

    CopyResultCollection results = new CopyResultCollection();
    Holder resultHolder = new Holder(results);
    Holder longHolder = new Holder(new Long(-1));

    //make the call to upload
    port.copyIntoItems(sourceUrl, destinationUrlCollection, fields, readAll(f), longHolder,resultHolder);

    //does not seem to change based on different CopyResults
    logger.debug("Long holder: " + longHolder.value);

    //do something meaningful here
    for (CopyResult copyResult : resultHolder.value.getCopyResult()) {              
        logger.debug("Destination: " + copyResult.getDestinationUrl());
        logger.debug("Error Message: " + copyResult.getErrorMessage());
        logger.debug("Error Code: " + copyResult.getErrorCode());
        if(copyResult.getErrorCode() != CopyErrorCode.SUCCESS)
            throw new Exception("Upload failed for: " + copyResult.getDestinationUrl() + " Message: " 
                    + copyResult.getErrorMessage() + " Code: " +   copyResult.getErrorCode() );
    }

}
```

Comment: how should I handle SharePoint authentication since I will be running this script from unix?

Comment: Its explained in the article. There is a sample source code available which you can try.